# Read a value from GetALexDataInJSONResult JSON array in Node .js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Read a value from JSON array in Node .js

my response

```
   {
    "GetALexDataInJSONResult": [
        {
            "projectid": 6,
            "FullName": "Four laning of Deoli- Kota Section of NH-12 from Km 165.000 to Junction of NH-76 on  Kota Bypass in the State of Rajasthan on BOT (Toll) project on DBFOT pattern under NHDP Phase-III.",
            "piu": "PIU Kota",
            "NumberofLanes": "4L",
            "NHNo_New": "52",
            "NHNo_Old": "12",
            "Total_Length": 83.04,
            "state_name": "Rajasthan"
        }
}
```

I need to access the "FullName" value from the following array -

error

```
 throw err;
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at FullNameIntent.customNode (C:\Users\SKBHATI\Desktop\CodeAlexaProject\AlexaNHAIProject\lambda\custom\index.js:64:60)
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (C:\Users\SKBHATI\Desktop\CodeAlexaProject\AlexaNHAIProject\lambda\custom\index.js:137:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:165:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

Comment: nameOfObject.GetALexDataInJSONResult[0].FullName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj =    {
    "GetALexDataInJSONResult": [
        {
            "projectid": 6,
            "FullName": "Four laning of Deoli- Kota Section of NH-12 from Km 165.000 to Junction of NH-76 on  Kota Bypass in the State of Rajasthan on BOT (Toll) project on DBFOT pattern under NHDP Phase-III.",
            "piu": "PIU Kota",
            "NumberofLanes": "4L",
            "NHNo_New": "52",
            "NHNo_Old": "12",
            "Total_Length": 83.04,
            "state_name": "Rajasthan"
        }
     ]
}

var myObj = JSON.parse(obj);
var fullName = myObj["GetALexDataInJSONResult"][0]["FullName"]
```

Comment: not get error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: because in your example the array is not enclosed `[ ]` properly. try this now.

Comment: done work after remove my another function code JSON.stringify

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(body.toString())["GetALexDataInJSONResult"][0]["FullName"]); final code

Comment: Glad I could help, select as answer if this helped you.

Comment: how to check size this JSON JSON.parse(body.toString())["GetALexDataInJSONResult"]